What do the letters mean on Arachne's outfits?
When I get an outfit from Arachne in Erebus, there's a letter to the left of each outfit description. Similar letters also appear when getting something from

 Chaos, Narcissus, Plaintive Echoes, Hades, and some boons from Artemis.

What do these letters mean?


This is speculation on my part, but I'm pretty sure that it's a placeholder for missing art assets.  The game is still in early access, and many of the art assets are still missing.  The most obvious example of this is that several characters are depicted as cloaked figures (and others are sketches rather than finished portraits), but Boons and other gifts also have assets associated with them, and need placeholders if those assets are not complete.
The letters probably indicate that they're different versions of the asset in question.  Possibly rarity?

Given that the letters are replaced with dress designs now, this is sorta confirmed?
